# Cakephp get email body without sending

Tags: php, email, cakephp-2.0

Using CakePHP 2.0, is it possible to get the body of the email without actually sending the email? I wish to get the body as I'll be using AWS to send the actual email and just using CakeEmail to build the body of the email.

I load the CakePHP library using composer once I upload the application to the server so the solution shouldn't involve making changes to the library files.

I'm currently trying to use the following -

```
$content = $email->template('register_email', 'default')
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->viewVars($email_data)
    ->message('html');
```

But `$content` is coming up as empty.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Thanks and regards,

Prathamesh.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to get this done. In the `email.php` configuration file, I set up the `EmailConfig` class as the following

```
class EmailConfig {

    public $default = array(
        'transport' => 'Debug',
        'from'=>abc@test.com,
        'to'=>abc@test.com
    );

}
```

Then when getting the body I used the following code -

```
App::uses('CakeEmail','Network/Email');
$email = new CakeEmail();
$content = $email->template('register_email', 'default')
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->viewVars($email_data)
    ->send();

$email_body = $content['message'];
```

And that's how you can get the body of the email without actually sending it.